SQL filter rows by range overlap
I have a snowflake table that roughly resembles the below. I want to filter out all rows that have the same name, provider and an overlapping voltage range.
Before:



NAME
Provider
Min_Volt
Max_Volt




OSMO
Bell
10
100


OSMO
Bell
80
150


OSMO
Bell
120
155


OSMO
Bell
160
200


MASD
Tele
80
150



After:



NAME
Provider
Min_Volt
Max_Volt




OSMO
Bell
160
200


MASD
Tele
80
150



Doing only the name and voltage is straightforward with a group by and count() > 1. But I don't know how to apply compare the rows to each other individually like that.
I was thinking of doing it with min/max window functions like
with min_max AS (
SELECT NAME
     , PROVIDER
     , MIN_VOLT
     , MAX_VOLT
     , MAX(max_volt) OVER (PARTITION BY PROVIDER, NAME) AS set_max
     , MIN(min_volt) OVER (PARTITION BY PROVIDER, NAME) AS set_min
FROM Table
)
SELECT NAME, PROVIDER, MIN_VOLT, MAX_VOLT
     FROM min_max
        WHERE MIN_VOLT NOT BETWEEN set_min AND set_min AND MAX_VOLT NOT BETWEEN set_min AND set_max;

However this returns no rows since its including the row its comparing in the max/min range. I'm not sure how to have it compare each row independently to each other row.
EDIT: For clarity - the rows we want to remove are those that have an overlapping voltage range with another row that has the same NAME and PROVIDER value. For example rows 1, 2 and 3 in the before table above all have the same name and provider, and there is overlap in the voltage range (10-100, 80-150, 120-155) so they should all be removed. Whereas Row 4 has the same name and provider but its voltage range doesn't overlap with the other rows so it should be kept.

How do you know which row to keep?

Are you saying remove the top 3 as the next row min_volt is within the one above, in the example 80 is between 10 and 100?

@Nathan_Sav, yep exactly, then row 4 would be kept as its range doesn't lay within the others.

I added more details to the post @Charlieface

I think you should add another row to your sample data, such as MASD, Tele, 160, 180 for demonstrating that you would keep both rows for MASD-Tele since there is no overlap.

Looks like LEAD and LAG should do the trick
with min_max AS (
    SELECT
       NAME
     , PROVIDER
     , MIN_VOLT
     , MAX_VOLT
     , LAG(MAX_VOLT) OVER (PARTITION BY PROVIDER, NAME ORDER BY MIN_VOLT, MAX_VOLT) AS prev_max
     , LEAD(MIN_VOLT) OVER (PARTITION BY PROVIDER, NAME ORDER BY MIN_VOLT, MAX_VOLT) AS next_min
    FROM ORENNIA_ANALYTICS_QC.ORENNIA.PRE_PROCESSED_SUBSTATIONS
)
SELECT
    NAME,
    PROVIDER,
    MIN_VOLT,
    MAX_VOLT
FROM min_max
WHERE (prev_max IS NULL OR MIN_VOLT > prev_max)
  AND (next_min IS NULL OR MAX_VOLT < next_min);

db<>fiddle

This work great. Thank you!

You could try an existence check
select *
from my_table a
where not exists(select *
                 from my_table b
                 where a.name = b.name and 
                       a.provider = b.provider and
                       a.min_volt <> b.min_volt and 
                       a.max_volt <> b.max_volt and
                       ((a.min_volt between b.min_volt and b.max_volt) or 
                        (a.max_volt between b.min_volt and b.max_volt)));

